# scientific way to say wash your hands

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, scientific-language

What would be a scientific way to tell people to wash their hands? In a way that it wouldn't sound like simply washing hands but more like a newly discovered method against corona virus.

I'm thinking of something like "Apply a high PH value solution to your hands...". But my chemical background is very thin, so that is as far as I got.

The reason is, I want to make a sign for the bathroom at work, that will make people think more, than just a "Wash your hands" sign. It should sound like an effective new cure, not just the boring old thing that mama told you since childhood. Many of my colleagues like riddles (our boss sends a weekly riddle around) and if they think enough about it, it will motivate them more to wash their hands. I'm not sure whether it will work, that remains to be seen.

*Note: I hope this is the right Stackexchange. I have seen a few other questions where people inquired about the scientific way to say something, however usually in a scientific context. This question is just from daily life. If there is a more fitting stackexchange, I would be grateful if you could point me in the right direction or even migrate the question directly.*

Comment: Why do you want to give practical, important advice in an obfuscated way?

Comment: I don't know about any one else but I usually say: "Ablute the forearm extremities with an apposite surfactant containing traditional carboxylates or synthetic anionic detergents for not less that one and one third moments".

Comment: @findusl - Which part of "wash your hands" is unscientific?

Comment: Indeed the way @Greybeard formulated it is what I was looking for. Could you make that into an answer?

Comment: @Damila because some people don't listen anymore when you just say "Wash your hands". It just sounds way to simple and boring to be effective. If you make it sound more scientific people may be thinking about it. I don't want to start a psychological discussion about that, I just want to try it out.

Comment: From those people who downvoted, could you give a reason? I assume you think this is not fitting for this stackexchange. Could you provide a more suitable stackexchange?

Comment: @findusl, it is true that, so far as the letter of the rules is concerned, this question is within the scope of this site. It is, however, at odds with its spirit. Many of the people who regularly contribute to it are deeply committed to fighting obfuscation, and would regard it as unethical to use their expertise to promote deliberate obfuscation (except perhaps jokingly, as was done by Greybeard).

Comment: @findust I agree entirely with jsw2, and would add that some context to explain your motivation for this question would have helped.

Comment: @Greybeard I added some motivation, maybe that helps. Will you make your comment into an answer? I like it very much.

Answer (score 2):

You could say "decontaminate your hands". On [this site](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK115266/) the phrase "hand decontamination" is used, therefore it is but a small step to take to say that. In fact, the phrase "to decontaminate your hands" itself is used in it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't suggest it as anything other than a joke, but

"Ablute the forearm extremities topically with an apposite surfactant containing traditional carboxylates or synthetic anionic detergents for not less that one and one third moments."

**To ablute** = to wash (rare)

**Extremities** = the hands and feet (hence the qualifying “forearm”)

**Surfactant** = a wetting agent, something that rediuces surface tension

**Carboxylates** – the active ingredient of common soap

**synthetic anionic detergents** = A man-made cleansing agent

**a moment** = obsolete measurement of time equal, approximately to 91 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Medical staff refer to 'scrubbing up' when they thoroughly wash their hands and forearms.

> Definition of **scrub up**
>
> : to wash one's hands and arms thoroughly
>
> The doctor scrubbed up for surgery.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scrub%20up)